# For Loop from Core Data

Tags: core-data, for-loop, uilocalnotification, nsfetchrequest

I have a question, I have 2 arrays (date and descriere), one is keeping a date which I select from a datePicker the other one is an array with strings, Both arrays are fetched from CoreData.

```
-(void)generateLocalNotification {
    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AddEntrySettings"];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    NSArray *result = [coreDataStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *date = [result valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSMutableArray *descriere = [result valueForKey:@"descriere"];`

    if (date != nil) {
        for (NSString *stringDate in date) {
            NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"];
            [format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
            self.date = [format dateFromString:stringDate];
            NSLog(@"LOG:%@",date);
            localNotification.fireDate = [self.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];
            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];

            for (int i = 0; i < descriere.count; i++) {
                localNotification.alertBody = descriere[i];
            }
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            localNotification.userInfo = @{@"id" : @42};

            UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
            [app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to fireDate everything is working fine, every time when a date from array is matching with local time I receive a notification till I try to add alertBody, when I make a for loop for alertBody every time is showing just last entry from my NSArray. In CoreData the both entries I adding in the same time. Where is my mistake? How can I make every time to receive a notification with alertBody that matching with date that I insert in CoreData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this for loop:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < descriere.count; i++) {
            localNotification.alertBody = descriere[i];
        }
```

will, for every `stringDate`, iterate to the last item in your descriere array.  What you want is to find the index of `stringDate` in `date`, and then find the string at the same index in `descriere`.

But there is an easier way.  Don't unpack `result` into two separate arrays, just access the different values from within the for loop:

```
if (result != nil) {
    for (NSDictionary *dict in result) {
        NSString *stringDate = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];
        // if necessary, test whether stringDate is nil here
        NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"];
        [format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone  timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
        self.date = [format dateFromString:stringDate];
        NSLog(@"LOG:%@",date);
        localNotification.fireDate = [self.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:0];
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];

        localNotification.alertBody = [dict objectForKey:@"descriere"];          
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.userInfo = @{@"id" : @42};

        UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        [app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    }
}
```